# Favorite Questions and Answers from fourth quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from October 1st 2016 through December 31 2016 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers.**).

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/10/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/10/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/10/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

**Notice:**

There appears to be some confusion about what is accepted. There is nothing wrong with promoting your own questions and answers. There is no point in down-voting anyone's answer to this meta question, everything gets included in the post.

Comment: Why was this **question** downvoted? Is that some sort of gag about the last paragraph?

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida - People who don’t think there should be announcements on meta.

Comment: @Adamant Who are these people?

Comment: Frankly I don't care if I only get down-votes, as long as I also get **responses.**

Comment: @KutuluMike - To be clear, I didn’t downvote; I’m just speculating as to why these seemingly innocuous questions get downvotes.

Comment: @KutuluMike "Love it or leave it", that what you're saying?

Comment: I couldn't be bothered this time around. Too many downvotes and snarky comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were no submitted user favorites.

The post has been created here [Highlights from 2016 – 4th Quarter](http://thesffblog.com/2017/01/highlights-from-2016-4th-quarter/)